# First time using Android Studio and I'm getting INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm starting to study Android Development but, when I try to run my app on my phone it says "NSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES". I searched online for this issue and I found that I need to sign my APK to work on my android phone.

So, I went to Build > Generate Signed Bundled or APK > APK, filled all the needed fields and then tried again to run my app on my phone, but show up again the same error. What I wrong? Sorry but this is my first time trying to coding an android app and I not found any solution to my problem.

Comment: Make sure to install the correct APK file (the signed one). Android Studio usually shows a notification that allows you to locate the APK file. Note that the build folder (and sub dirs) may contain many other APK files of the same name.